# Auto imports React hooks for Lerna monorepo

Tags: typescript, import, monorepo, tsconfig, lerna

I have an monorepo that use Lerna, and i have 4 packages inside:

1. Client Frontend
2. Admin Frontend
3. Components
4. Reusable packages

for Frontend I'm using React, and in reusable packages i have it as dependencies

**Reusable packages**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
   }
```

in all another packages i just install it as dependencies:

**Client, Admin, Components packages**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Reusable-packages": "*"
  }
```

but in all these 3 packages i cannot use auto-imports for react hooks, but i can build/run/deploy my aplication
if i install `"@types/react": "18.2.15",` to my pacakges auto-import will appear

I tried add "@types/react": "18.2.15"` to all packages and it helps, but i don't need it with lerna
it can be issue with tsconfig or package.json, but i cannot find what can response for it

i tried to add it and it doesn't help

```
"declaration": true,
"declarationMap": true,
```

Comment: Because you've specified `@types/react` as a `devDependency`. This means that it's used to develop your package but not to consume it. Since `react` is a `dependency`, `@types/react` should also be a `dependency`.